# Change object without referring to it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is the following possible:

```
var someObject = {someProperty : "someValue"};
var someFunction = function() {
 someProperty = "anotherValue";
};

// what do I do here, in order to use
// someFunction to change someObject without
// directly accessing it from someFunction?
// E.g., none of this:
/*
   var someFunction = function() {
       someObject.someProperty = "anotherValue";
   };
*/

if(someObject.someProperty=="anotherValue") alert("Hooray!");
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: I see you have mentioned GreaseMonkey in some comments. Note that GreaseMonkey scripts run in a sandboxed environment with different behavior than running a script straight in a browser. 
http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Environment  
 http://wiki.greasespot.net/Global_object

Comment: I'm not writing this code for Greasemonkey. I wrote that it's working under a Firefox extension. Also I'm well aware of GM's sandboxed nature, which is what I'm trying to replicate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read my question and seeing the lack of understanding, here is a simple way that it can be handled (add a parameter):

```js
var someObject = {someProperty : "someValue"};
var someFunction = function(ref) {
 ref.someProperty = "anotherValue";
};

someFunction(someObject);

// assert(someObject.someProperty=="anotherValue");
```

Comment: Of course any code you write using that isn't really portable JavaScript. I see on your profile you develop a lot of GreaseMonkey scripts, and so are probably accustomed to this behaviour. My recommendation is to move past your comfort zone and do things in a more generic JavaScript way. I would recommend much of Douglas Crockford's work as a source of knowledge/inspiration.

That's just my 2 cents.

Comment: I said that was my 2 cents because I wanted to be clear that I wasn't imposing my perspective too strongly. Having said that, everyone on this page says it can't be done. What they really mean is they don't think it's worth the trouble. If you really want, you can implement your own language in JavaScript with any semantics you want. Here's a parser/lexer generator for JS in JS to get you started. http://jscc.jmksf.com/

Comment: I've updated the answer. I was coding a Firefox addon which was very restrictive about what could be run. I hope the revision makes it clearer for anyone else trying to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

For purely academic purpose, here's a way:

```
with (someObject) {
  eval('(' +someFunction.toString() + ')();');
}
```

Don't use this in production environment!

**[Edit]:** Just to clarify, here's how you use it.

```
var someObject = {someProperty : "someValue"};
var someFunction = function() {
 someProperty = "anotherValue";
};

with (someObject) {
  eval('(' +someFunction.toString() + ')();');
}

if(someObject.someProperty=="anotherValue") alert("Hooray!");
```

It *DOES NOT* refer to someObject inside someFunction.

Comment: That refers to "someObject" inside the function body. The point is finding a way not to do this.

Comment: Your question does not mention that. You say you can't modify either `someObject` or `someFunction` and you can't refer to `someObject` _inside_ `someFunction`. This approach does neither.

Comment: I guess that does it, but it uses "with" and "eval", two of the last things anyone  would want to use. I was hoping for some clever use of "apply" / "call" to allow this, but I guess it just isn't possible nicely.

Comment: `apply/call` are for defining the context, not scope. So yeah, they're useless unless you want to refer `this`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

```
var someFunction = function() {
    someProperty = "anotherValue";
};
```

Here someProperty is a global variable (created if not accessed before).

```
var someObject = {someProperty : "someValue"};
```

Here someProperty is a key of an object (not a variable).

So in each context the token someProperty refers to something different and completely independent.

There is no way for the function to alter the value of the object without a direct reference / calling another function to do it.

Comment: I realize the difference between a key and a variable. Is this really not possible? I know the developers of Greasemonkey have done it somehow, but their source code is a mess.

Comment: The best you can get without modifying your code more is @Phil Ross' reply, in which "this" is a reference to the object, but as I said, you allways need such a reference one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval("someObject.someProperty='anotherValue'");
```

Will that work? What do you consider "directly accessing "someObject" in someFunction?" You're going to have to access someObject somehow if you want to change its property...

Comment: By that,  I mean literally typing "someObject." in  someFunction. I want the code to work as it appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to modify your function to reference `this.someProperty` instead of just `someProperty`, then you can use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call):

```
var someFunction = function() {
  this.someProperty = "anotherValue";
};

someFunction.apply(someObject);
```

Comment: I want to use something other than "apply". The idea is to be able to type code freely in the function without worrying about "this." or "someObject."

Answer (score 0):

No. This is all about scoping (environments) and properties.

When you say `someObject = ...` or `someobject.whatever` what you are saying is give me the `someObject` in the nearest scope and then do something with it.

Scopes nest. Functions create a new scope and capture the surrounding scope. Variables in closer scopes can shadow variables in surrounding scopes.
Your function can see everything in the scope it was declared in, so it can see `someObject`.

`someProperty` is part of a key/value pair in `someObject`. Nothing cat get to it without going through `someObject` and asking it to retreive the value stored with the key `someProperty`.

Comment: Actually, someObject is in the scope of "window", as is every "global" object. The point is changing the main object from "window" to "someObject".

Answer (score 0):

```
var someObject = {someProperty : "someValue"};
with (someObject)
{
  window.someFunction = function() {
   someProperty = "anotherValue";
  };
}

if(someObject.someProperty=="anotherValue") alert("Hooray!");
```

Not the best coding practice but should perform what you want.